# MvvmCross: How to set MvxCollectionViewController's itemsize to take up the full screen size?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

How to set the ItemSize as full size width and height? Also dynamic change the ItemSize based when rotated the screen?

```
 public class SearchResultView : MvxCollectionViewController
    {
        private bool _isInitialised;

        public SearchResultView()
            : base(new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            {
                ItemSize = new SizeF(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height),
                ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal,
            })
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to set the ItemSize as full size width and height? Also dynamic change the ItemSize based when rotated the screen?

You could change the layout of the collection view during DidRotate - e.g.:

```
public override void DidRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
{
    CollectionView.SetCollectionViewLayout(new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        {
            ItemSize = new SizeF(View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal,
        });
}
```

To make this effect produce a nice visual display, I guess that your Collection View Cells (and any supplementary views) would also need to resize.